# Only Margin-top is working but not top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align my login page with the css. However, i have a problem between the two property margin-top and top. Margin-top tend to push the login page based on the first element, while top is just the position of the login page. Therefore, i cannot use margin-top in my media query codes. Unfortunately, top isn't working as well

This is how i added the top property in my CSS

```
#loginpage {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
top:-42%;
}
```

which is not working.

Only this is working

```
margin-top:-20%;
```

Above my loginpage, there's a slideshow header and a twitterbootstrap navbar

```
#twitterbootstrap {
    position: relative;
}

#SlideshowHome {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 6%;
    height: 20%;
}
```

This is my loginpage

```
 <div id="loginpage">
    <table id="loginpage1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

       <td>
          <b>  Username : </b> <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td>
           <b> Password : </b> <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" ></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

This is also my twitterbootstrap and slideshow header

```
 <div id="SlideshowHome">
 <img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" style="width:100%; height:150%">
```

```
</div>
<div id="twitterbootstrap">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">iPolice's Menu</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="Login.aspx">Login</a></li>
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li><a href="RecoverPassword.aspx">Recover Password</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/singaporepoliceforce?ref=ts&fref=ts"><img src="image/facebook.jpg" style="width:100px; height:30px"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/SingaporePolice"><img src="image/twitter.jpg" style="width:100px; height:30px"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Therefore, may i ask why does only margin-top changes the position but not top?

Comment: share your html source

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML and if possible a fiddle/jsBin/...?

Comment: @Fags i've just pasted it above.

Comment: @dc5 I dont think i can put asp.net things into jsfiddle i suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of `top` in percent is based on the height of the containing block - see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props - while `margin-top` in percent is based on the WIDTH of the containing block - see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties - causing a difference in size.

So if my guess is correct and your login page only contains absolutely positioned divs, then the containing block, the body, is functionally empty and doesn't have any height.
It does have its standard width of 100% of the window, so that's why `top-margin` works but not `top`.

Solution: give the container a height explicitly.

Comment: however, the problem is, in my desktop it's looking fine, pretty close to my slideshow header `http://sipolice.azurewebsites.net/` but when i put it on my phone, it becomes the otherwise. Therefore, my container is actually already fitting nicely just below the slideshow header.

Comment: It's working fine on a big computer but not on a phone? You never mentioned that in your question. I think it's best if you add that. Also, what phone and what browser?